# Serving Notice after receiving new offer But HR mails Not coming after that

Tags: new-job, resignation, notice-period

I have resigned from my position in my current company and served a two month notice after receiving an offer from another company.

The new company is multinational, so they provided the forms and HR confirmed over mail about my start date, offer letter and other documents related for on-boarding.

But after the first series of emails, I stopped hearing from them. So I fear that they rejected my application. Are my fears wrong?

In the last mail, they mentioned if they can use a buy-out option to shorten the notice as they have a global project running. They also shared the offer with the company head by mail and also discussed salary details.

Comment: So your question is?

Comment: Is it normal that i stopped hearing from them? Is my fear wrong?

Comment: Consider editing your post to include such questions, making sure they are on topic. Wrote an answer, hope it helps you :)

Comment: Did you sign an actual contract? What does "stopped hearing from them" mean? How long was it since you heard from them? Why is HR "discussing salary details" with their CEO after you already accepted an offer? None of this makes much sense to me.

Comment: hi @Lilienthal, Thanks for reply. Stopped hearing means I have not received any communication from them about more then a week. And I have not said "discussing", they shred discussed salary details on mail as confirmation. By the worry is, offer is withdrawn as more then week passed without any communication. But answer below reduces my worries a bit.

Comment: and also you reduced point. Thanks though for your time.

Comment: If they have nothing to tell you, why would you hear from them? You certainly shouldn't expect mails every few days for 2 months, just for the sake of reassurance.

Comment: point understood @Dukeling .

Comment: @Dukeling, but how do I know They don't have anything to tell me. Communication is the only key here.  In My experience HR keeps update when candidate will be joining, reliving date, if on-boarding in new city then accomodation. This is new experience so shared for experts view here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that they have rejected your application, first because they already offered you a start date and also because they seem to have already considered and decided they want you there and even wish to speed up your notice period.

Application processes take time, and short periods of no replies are not rare, as they are usually occupied with some other tasks or well processing your candidacy and the required paperwork.

I would wait at least 3 days (or even a week) before getting worried. If that happens, you can try *reaching out to them* (via the email you have been using perhaps) and politely ask them for any news on the process, as well as offering your assistance in case they need anything else from you.

In future occasions, I would suggest you try to coordinate your job changes in a way that enables you to *give your notice period after getting/signing a definitive offer or contract*, so you spare yourself from being caught in uncertain and stressful situations like this one, or even worse, quitting just to find out they withdrew their offer.

Answer (score 0):

Resignation letters are revocable. But make sure that the new company you're trying to get into really has stopped the process.

Check your countries' laws on contracts on what may be the issue that you can sue the company for if they are not honoring your *signed* employment contract.